# K3 surfaces with small Picard number and symmetry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, k3-surfaces

I am looking for examples of K3 surfaces that have a low Picard rank and at least one holomorphic involution.
Here, *low* is no mathematically precise concept.
I want to do computations with Monad bundles and for that lower is better for me.
For Picard rank bigger than 5 those computations become too difficult for me.

For example, the very general branched double cover of $\mathbb{CP}^2$ branched over a sextic has $Pic \simeq \mathbb{Z}$ and the map that swaps the two sheets of the cover is a holomorphic involution.

The post [Picard groups of quartic K3 surfaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/238006/picard-groups-of-quartic-k3-surfaces) contains more examples of K3 surfaces with Picard ranks 1, 2, and 3, but I didn't find any holomorphic involutions of the K3 surfaces mentioned there.

Answer (score 6):

In Section 9 of the paper

I. Shimada: [An algorithm to compute automorphism groups of (K3) surfaces and an application to singular (K3) surfaces](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/imrn/rnv006), *Int. Math. Res. Not.* **2015**, No. 22, 11961-12014 (2015) [ZBL1333.14034](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1333.14034)

there are many examples of  complex elliptic K3 surfaces $X$ with Picard rank 3 and having (infinite) automorphism group  containing involutions (in fact, $\operatorname{Aut}(X)$ contains a copy of $\mathbb{Z}/2 \ast \mathbb{Z}/2$).

Comment: Example 1.1 from the paper is: a complex K3 surface X which has a Jacobian fibration and whose Neron–Severi lattice is prescribed. How do I know such a K3 surface exists? Also, it seems to follow from the first paragraph in section 11.5.3 in Hubrechts: Lectures on K3 surfaces that this K3 surface is algebraic. Is there a description of this K3 surface as an algebraic variety? (I come from a different field so don't know much about algebraic geometry as a whole.)